# Passar matriz como ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

Preciso fazer o proposto:

> Elabore uma função que receba como parâmetros um ponteiro de uma matriz, o número de linhas e colunas, e imprima os elementos da matriz.

Mas estou aprendendo ponteiros e tendo dificuldades, já tentei de diversas formas passar o ponteiro da matriz mas de todo jeito dá erro. Agora o erro está na linha:

```
            printf("\t%d",*mtr[lin][col]);
```

> ```
> [Error] invalid types 'int* (*)[4][int*]' for array subscript
> ```

Eis o meu código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int matriz_ponteiro(int *mtr[3][4], int *lin, int *col){
    // imprimir a matriz
    for (*lin=0; *lin<3; *lin++){
        printf("\n");
        for (*col=0; *col<4; *col++){
            printf("\t%d",*mtr[lin][col]);
        }   
    }
    return *mtr[lin][col];

}


int main (){
    int res, mtr [3][4];
    int lin, col, cont;
    cont = 0;
    // armazenar o valor de cont em cada posição da matriz
    for (lin=0; lin<3; lin++){
        for (col=0; col<4; col++){
            mtr[lin][col]= cont++;
        }
    }
    res = matriz_ponteiro(mtr[3][4], lin, col);
}
```

Comment: Tem algum motivo de usar esses ponteiros? Eles não são necessários.

Comment: Sim, sem ponteiro estava bem fácil... Mas o enunciado do exercício pede que a função receba como parâmetros um ponteiro de uma matriz  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código todo não faz muito sentido e em vários pontos não faz o que imagina. Ele pode ser simplificado, organizado e modernizado assim, aí funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matriz_ponteiro(int mtr[3][4]) {
     for (int lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) printf("\t%d", mtr[lin][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main () {
    int mtr[3][4];
    for (int lin = 0, cont = 0; lin < 3; lin++) for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) mtr[lin][col] = cont++;
    matriz_ponteiro(mtr);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qUaJs2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vooecwnu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/PassMatrix.c).

Pode ser que havia algum outro objetivo, mas isso não fica claro na pergunta, o que dá para inferir está aí. Se tiver dúvidas específicas pode fazer. Aprender a programar na tentativa e erro não é a forma mais produtiva, nem costuma dar muito certo.

Usando ponteiros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LINHA 3
#define COLUNA 4

void matriz_ponteiro(int **mtr, size_t linhas, size_t colunas) {
     for (int lin = 0; lin < linhas; lin++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < colunas; col++) printf("\t%d", mtr[lin][col]);
  
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main () {
    int **mtr = malloc(LINHA * sizeof(*mtr));
    for (int lin = 0, cont = 0; lin < LINHA; lin++) {
        mtr[lin] = malloc(COLUNA * sizeof(*mtr[lin]));
        for (int col = 0; col < COLUNA; col++) mtr[lin][col] = cont++;
    }
    matriz_ponteiro(mtr, LINHA, COLUNA);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yG6wcC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ziexpscp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MatrixAsPointer.c).

Comment: Sim, dessa forma funciona, mas vc não está usando ponteiros... E o exercício proposto solicita que : Elabore uma função que receba como parâmetros um **ponteiro de uma matriz**, o número de linhas e colunas, e imprima os elementos da matriz

Comment: O problema é que isso não faz sentido.

Comment: @ADR fiz totalmente com ponteiros.

Comment: Vi aqui, mas está dando erro na linha:
      int **mtr = malloc(LINHA * sizeof(*mtr));

 [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int**' [-fpermissive]

Para você não deu erro?

Comment: @ADR você clicou nos *links* que eu forneci? Viu que está funcionando?

Comment: Claro, lá funciona.
Obg!!

Answer (score 5):

## Entendo o código - primeira alternativa

Olhe essa linha:

```
matriz_ponteiro(mtr[3][4], lin, col);
```

`lin` e `col` são do tipo `int`. `mtr` é uma matriz 3x4 do tipo `int`, e portanto `mtr[3]` é um array de 4 posições do tipo `int` e finalmente `mtr[3][4]` é um `int`. Ou seja, os três parâmetros que você passa são `int`s.

Na definição da função, temos isso:

```
int matriz_ponteiro(int *mtr[3][4], int *lin, int *col){
```

Ou seja, os parâmetros são dos tipos "*ponteiro para matriz 3x4 de `int`*", "*ponteiro para `int`*" e "*ponteiro para `int`*". Ou seja, não batem com aquilo que você usa para chamar mais em baixo.

Bem, no seu código você mistura matrizes, ponteiros e inteiros de forma mais ou menos ao acaso, o que demonstra que você não deve saber direito o que está fazendo, então vamos com calma. Aparentemente, o propósito da sua função `matriz_ponteiro` é imprimir a matriz. Portanto eis o cabeçalho dela:

```
void matriz_ponteiro(int mtr[3][4])
```

Por quê? Porque ela recebe uma matriz 3x4 de inteiros para imprimir (`int mtr[3][4]` e não devolve nenhum resultado (`void`).

Não são necessários os parâmetros `lin` e `col` porque ela vai percorrer todas as linhas e colunas. Assim sendo, a implementação é assim:

```
void matriz_ponteiro(int mtr[3][4]) {
    int lin, col;
    for (lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            printf("\t%d", mtr[lin][col]);
        }
    }
}
```

E com isso, no seu `main`, ao invés disso:

```
res = matriz_ponteiro(mtr[3][4], lin, col);
```

Use isso:

```
matriz_ponteiro(mtr);
```

E você também pode eliminar a variável `res`.

Eis como fica o seu código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matriz_ponteiro(int mtr[3][4]) {
    int lin, col;
    for (lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            printf("\t%d", mtr[lin][col]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int mtr[3][4];
    int lin, col, cont;
    cont = 0;
    // armazenar o valor de cont em cada posição da matriz
    for (lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            mtr[lin][col]= cont++;
        }

    }
    matriz_ponteiro(mtr);
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/5ZZLLl)

## Segunda alternativa

Se você tiver que ter o número de linhas e colunas como parâmetro, pode fazer isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matriz_ponteiro(int linhas, int colunas, int matriz[linhas][colunas]) {
    int lin, col;
    for (lin = 0; lin < linhas; lin++) {
        for (col = 0; col < colunas; col++) {
            printf("\t%d", matriz[lin][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int mtr[3][4];
    int lin, col, cont;
    cont = 0;
    // armazenar o valor de cont em cada posição da matriz
    for (lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            mtr[lin][col] = cont++;
        }
    }
    matriz_ponteiro(3, 4, mtr);
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/DZ1mac) É importante se notar de que a matriz tem que ser o último parâmetro, pois a definição dela depende do número de linhas e de colunas que tem que ser declaradas antes (ou seja, nos parâmetros anteriores).

A matriz utilizada lá é um ponteiro. Para provar isso, experimente colocar no final da função `matriz_ponteiro`, isso:

```
    mtr[0][0] = 1234;
```

E no final do `main`, use isso duas vezes:

```
    matriz_ponteiro(3, 4, mtr);
```

E você vai perceber que a matriz de fato é alterada de dentro do `matriz_ponteiro`. Se ela fosse apenas copiada, o 1234 não ia aparecer ao chamar a função `matriz_ponteiro` novamente. Isso só é possível porque ocorreu uma passagem de referência, e não apenas de valores. E se ocorreu passagem de referência em C, é porque houve passagem de ponteiro.

## Terceira alternativa

Entretanto, se você quiser que a função `matriz_ponteiro` receba um ponteiro explícito, então pode fazer assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void matriz_ponteiro(int *matriz, int linhas, int colunas) {
    int lin, col;
    for (lin = 0; lin < linhas; lin++) {
        if (lin != 0) printf("\n");
        for (col = 0; col < colunas; col++) {
            printf("\t%d", matriz[lin * colunas + col]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int mtr[3][4];
    int lin, col, cont;
    cont = 0;
    // armazenar o valor de cont em cada posição da matriz
    for (lin = 0; lin < 3; lin++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            mtr[lin][col] = cont++;
        }

    }
    matriz_ponteiro(mtr[0], 3, 4);
}
```

[Veja funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/uGJpLi)

Esse `matriz[lin * colunas + col]` precisa de uma melhor explicação. O que acontece é que os elementos da matriz são colocados na forma de uma linha atrás da outra. Ou seja, a matriz consiste de uma sequência de linhas e cada linha tem um número de elementos igual ao número de colunas. Isso também pode ser interpretado como um array com `linhas * colunas` elementos. Essa fórmula `lin * colunas + col` acessa o elemento desejado se você estiver utilizando essa forma de indexação.

O uso de `mtr[0]` no final é porque o tipo tem que ser um `int *`, e não um `int **`. Uma outra forma seria fazer um cast explícito também (usar `(int *) mtr`).

Comment: Obrigada pelas explicações, mas coomo disse infelizmente o enunciado pede que a função receba como parâmetro um ponteiro de uma matriz. O que o seu código completo não resolve.
Sem ponteiro consigo fazer tbm, o problema é que ainda não entendi direito o uso de ponteiros.

Comment: @ADR Resposta editada. Está bom agora?

Comment: Sim, era exatamente isso que eu queria fazer. Muito obrigada :)